# Correlation between indoor temperatures and corona virus activity?

Tags: covid-19, coronavirus, covid-19-datasets

Had there been any research conducted on the correlation between expected daily indoor room temperatures of countries and coronavirus activity like daily new cases, mortality, and severity for the last 2 months.

If most of coronavirus transmission occurs indoors, then the question of indoor temperature effect on the virus seems to be very relevant.

Poor, or countries with devastated electrical systems, who cannot afford to have effective air conditioning would have their indoor temperatures more likely higher than other countries, and it appears that those countries are fairing better than the other countries?

If not, had there been any research for other viruses of the corona family regarding that correlation?

Any research on that area?

Comment: How is this different from [your other question on this subject?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/23186/why-not-increase-temperature-indoors-to-30-celsius-or-more-hydration-as-a-me)

Comment: I'm speaking about if there are statistical surveys done on that specific subject. The other question was about why there is no action done given the information present from corona virus maps versus temperature maps and the latter ones are not indoor temperature oriented maps, here I'm asking specifically about statistical survey research carried on indoor temperatures.

Comment: Ebola shares similar temperature characteristics to SARS-CoV-2 and spreads in Africa

Comment: @GrahamChiu, Yes but the mode of spread is different, disease that spread by direct contact seems to be unaffected by temperature, but conorna virus is spreading by aerosol like influenza, this would make it susceptible to temperature as aerosol droplets are known to be unstable by high humidity and temperatures from 5 to 30 celsius, and this agrees with the coronavirus map. However, the problem of close contacts remains unaffected by temperature but that would not cause  rapid transmission, it would be localized. see: http://sites.utoronto.ca/occmed/jscott/publications/2014_Savory_et_al.pdf

Comment: I meant by temperatures less than 5 C or above 30 C (as regards instability).